# MySQL: can I implement row-level AND column level security?

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

Say I have a table like this:

```
itemID | PriceA | PriceB | PriceC | other columns...
1      | 8.0    | 6.95   | 0.5    | ...
2      | 5.9    | 6.97   | 4.1    | ...
3      | 0.2    | 1.12   | 3.5    | ...
```

I want a user to login in, but only see certain rows, and only one Price column. For example, user Susie can see only rows 1 and 2, and only Price B for those items. User Hanna can see rows 2 and 3 at Price A.

Maybe it doesn't need to be database-level security. Basically, users will login-in on a **website** (a Wordpress) and, after logging-in, will see certain products at a certain price.

As well, more than one user can access any given row or column. It isn't a one-to-one relationship. I think this differs from typical row-level mysql security.

I have 2 questions:

1. Should this be database-level security or should it be something else? PHP code?
2. Any suggestions on how I can implement this?

Comment: php level. if you wanted in-db security, every single one of your users would have to have a DB-level login account, which is just downright dangerous/stupid/silly.

Comment: If the number of users is 20, is that still not feasible?

Comment: no. you never ever grant end users direct access to the DB.

Comment: check [Dialect](https://github.com/foo123/Dialect) a SQL construction framework, whcih supports programmable (soft-) custom views (ps i'm author)

Comment: @MarcB, I'm not sure I understand. The website will have to login to the database anyway, it's just a matter of which login credentials it uses. It can either login to a more "master" level of the DB, or a more restricted one. I would think this is a safer option.

Comment: yes, but you log in with one SINGLE database-level user account. like I said, your users should have no rights whatesoever to the database yourself. only YOUR code can directly deal with the DB.

Comment: @MarcB, I think as long as those credentials aren't the same as the "true" login credentials it should be fine. For example, I can add something on to that for the actual database connection and credentials (ex. username=[string_input]+"secret-ending"). 

Is that a good idea? 

(also: I don't have high enough reputation for chat on stackoverflow yet so I need to ask here)

Comment: mysql doesn't have row-level permission support anyways, so you'd have to implement at least SOME of your security in your app, so why not implement everything there, instead of smearing stuff across multiple systems?

Comment: Actually, I think creating views will solve my problem! Yes?

Comment: @Mel, probably (depending on use case and the rest of your code), that is why i posted my comment above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I think creating views will solve my problem. Does that seem secure?

I found this: [How can I allow users sql access to a table limited to certain rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16890170/how-can-i-allow-users-sql-access-to-a-table-limited-to-certain-rows)

Comment: Probably. But you cannot create views on-the-fly (or programmaticaly) (actually you can but it is not recommended), that is why i posted my comment above for programmable custom views (i use in some of my projects for exactly this reason)