# MYSQL: How can I gain security at row-level?

Tags: mysql, security, authorization, access-control

I'm working on a project that involves researching about how to gain fine-grained access control (FGAC) in MYSQL database.

From my searching, I think that FGAC related to security at the row-level in MySQL. However, I've looked through many websites but I can only see one method which is using VIEW in MySQL.

Reference: https://www.sqlmaestro.com/resources/all/row_level_security_mysql/

I think there are still a lot of other methods to gain row-level access control, am i right?
Can anyone show me other methods as if there is only one method, it would be very little for me to write on my document.

Ps: Any limitations related to that method is also valuable for me.

Comment: implementing this with a VIEW is the best method because the columns and the records are then still visible within MySQL GUI clients like PHPmyADMIN, SQLYog.. "I think there are still a lot of other methods to gain row-level access control, am i right? " Yes the other methods like using a stored procedure hides the columns and records from the user...

Comment: Aside from using stored procedure, can you think of anything else, so that I can look it up immediately. The more method I mentioned in my research, the better my score as my professor require as many methods as I can find. Thank you!

Comment: This question might be a duplication off https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15105052/mysql-user-row-level-access

Comment: Besides https://www.sqlmaestro.com/resources/all/row_level_security_mysql/ is a pretty old article.. Iám pretty sure that in MySQL 5.7+ you can replace the trigger code to make use off generated columns instead. Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html

Comment: if the reseach may contain alternatives about other databases, suggest using PostgreSQL .. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/ddl-rowsecurity.html or Oracle http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TDPSG/ instead….. Any why your better off using a database which supports this out off the box vs self implementations, that is what research is about i think.

Comment: Well, the thing is, my research is limit to MySQL database, so it is very hard for me to switch to other databases.
I don't quite understand about the part you said to replace the trigger code. Can you explain to me in more detail

Comment: "Well, the thing is, my research is limit to MySQL database" Creating your custom storage engine (  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/custom-engine.html ) or extending a existing one.. to support row level access also might be a **very** good reseach point

Comment: Thank you. Also, I read that "use proxy with custom rules restricting access" is also a valid, isn't it. But I cannot find any sources about using proxy to gain FGAC, can you help me?

Comment: "I don't quite understand about the part you said to replace the trigger code. Can you explain to me in more detail –"  i beleive in MySQL 5.7+ you can use `owner VARCHAR(30) AS (SUBSTRING_INDEX(USER(), '@', 1)) STORED` in the create table statement instead of using the insert and update triggers check this "STORED: Column values are evaluated and stored when rows are inserted or updated. A stored column does require storage space and can be indexed. " source https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your detail explaination. However, can you clarify me about using proxy to achieve row-level access control as it is mentioned in this answer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16890170/how-can-i-allow-users-sql-access-to-a-table-limited-to-certain-rows

Comment: MySQL Proxy allows LUA scripting  look like it's indeed possible looking into the LUA functions. http://download.nust.na/pub6/mysql/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-proxy-scripting.html or https://downloads.mysql.com/docs/mysql-proxy-en.a4.pdf or http://datacharmer.org/presentations/mysqluniv_2008/advanced_lua.pdf .. But MySQL Proxy is "deprecated" (MySQL Proxy is not GA, and is not recommended for Production use.
We recommend MySQL Router for production use.) don't know if MySQLRouter can use LUA scripting.

Comment: Hi, I have looked at the link you've given, but it contains only general information about the syntax. Can you recommend me any useful sites that shows the implementation of custom storage engine with row-level access control? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are products (open source and commercial) that address these use cases. The area is known as dynamic data filtering or dynamic data masking. Data virtualization is also a technique that can achieve what you want.

Look into Informatica, Axiomatics, Denodo, and others

Comment: Are these solutions external product or they are native MySQL method because my project requires working with MySQL only.

Comment: These are proxy-based i.e. they sit in front of your database. If you want to use MySQL only, then look into FGAC.

Comment: I have looked into FGAC, however, I can only find resources about uisng VIEW. I want to have some other method to achieve FGAC as well, can you recommend me some other methods?

Comment: Hi @DN96, I don't believe there are other methods in MySQL to achieve true FGAC. There is really just the limited feature of VIEW in MySQL. David's answer is the correct one in my opinion.