# Mysql - Appending a condition at the end of a user given query

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a UI, where users can run MySQL queries.
But the results will be filtered based on the users. For which I'll have to append a condition at the end. Also, have to add a limit and offset's by checking.

```
( select test1,test2 from table1 Inner Join table2 on table1.condition = table2.condition ) where condition1 = 'user1' and condition2 = 'user2'
```

The query inside the parenthesis is given by the user and the where the condition is appended in the code. 
Currently, I'm parsing the whole query to find the position of the table name. Its also have an issue when using inner joins like finding the table name

Is there a better way to implement this?

Comment: Create a MySql view using join then filter from the view.

Comment: Which language do you use? What about modifying the SQL by coding?

Comment: We don't actually know it restricting access is your goal (you should elaborate on that to get some ideas), but assuming it is, you may want to check out [How can I allow users sql access to a table limited to certain rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16890170/6248528). It is *very* unlikely that an approach like yours - allowing the user to access forbidden data and then filter the outcome, and hope noone writes a query to outsmart your filter - will work. (If you heard the buzz about Spectre (the cpu bug, not 007): that was, very *very* simplified, basically the same problem).

Comment: hi @kiks73, i'm using nodejs

Comment: i'm thinking of creating a view and granting only `SELECT` operation. But what will be the overhead of creating a view ,as if there are 1000 customers i'll be creating 1000*3 table's view for that 1000 customers. Is it a right way? @SumeshTG

Comment: @Solarflare i'm thinking of creating a view and granting only SELECT operation. But what will be the overhead of creating a view ,as if there are 1000 customers i'll be creating 1000*3 table's view for that 1000 customers. Is it a right way?

Comment: The more appropriate way would probably be something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15105078/6248528) (end let the view e.g. include `where CURRENT_USER() = table.column_with_ownername`). On the other hand: you didn't elaborate on what you are doing, so we cannot tell you "the right way", as we do not know *for what* (and even then, there might be several options).